# Is it possible to change the box rule thickness of algorithm2e

Tags: color, rules, algorithm2e

Is it possible to customize the boxing rule width and color of an `algorithm2e` float?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
% \RestyleAlgo{boxed}
\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\LinesNumbered
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \caption{My algorithm\label{alg}}
  Statement
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i don't think there's a need here for the `[tikz-pgf]` tag?

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is a gray 4pt border around the algorithm environement (only a border) is that somehow possible, I messed around with ``mdframed`` which had problems with ``\begin{algorithm}[H]``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is going to break something else unexpectedly...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,regexpatch}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
  Statement
\end{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\algorithmboxrule}
\setlength{\algorithmboxrule}{2pt}

\newcommand{\algorithmboxcolor}{orange}

\xpatchcmd*{\algocf@caption@boxruled}{0.8pt}{2\algorithmboxrule}{}{}
\xpatchcmd*{\algocf@caption@boxruled}{\vrule}{\vrule width \algorithmboxrule}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\algocf@caption@boxruled}{\hrule}{\hrule height \algorithmboxrule}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\algocf@caption@boxruled}{\color{\algorithmboxcolor}}{}{}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule-\algorithmboxrule}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{\algorithmboxrule}
\makeatother

\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
  Statement
\end{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@algocf@post@boxed}{\framebox}{\color{\algorithmboxcolor}\framebox}{}{}
\makeatother

\RestyleAlgo{boxed}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
  Statement
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that the algorithm box is set using an `\fbox` (or `\framebox`). As such, an adjustment to the `\fboxsep` and/or `\fboxrule` has been applied where necessary. However, this could affect other locations where you use `\fbox`.

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is a gray 4pt border around the algorithm environement (only a border) is that somehow possible, I messed around with mdframed which had problems with \begin{algorithm}[H]

Comment: ahh you did that :-) hm... lets see :-)

Comment: when I try your example, it does not change the color, the thickness works ... ? do you know why? xcolor is loaded

Comment: @Gabriel: There are two type of boxed styles: `boxruled` and `boxed`. They each require their own magic. Which are you using? You should include all the referenced changes (between the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` markers)... there are two such blocks.

Comment: yours tuff works, sorry I used the wrong one